# Installer files for GPOs on SYSVOL or Dedicated Share?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, dfs

Say I wanted to deploy a number of software packages using GPOs, where a GPO would reference an absolute path to an installer file (i.e. installer.msi). What are the pros/cons of hosting installers directly within SYSVOL vs a separate file share implemented with DFS.

I'm seeing a number of guides saying a dedicated share should be created, but why? Are there security risks, replication issues, etc.?